# Disintegrate.js and htmlcanvas.min.js seem not working

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, i used disintegrate.js and html2canvas.min.js libraries to help me create a vanishing screen when an image is clicked on. But it seem not working. please help me out

I have tried reviewing the codes over and over to see if there is an issue but nothing yet.

I used npm to install the disintegrate and html5canvas respectively[image: html file picture[![the Javascript file]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

okay i think i came across this issue sometimes back but i didn't use npm to do it, i downloaded the disintegrate.js and html2canvas.min.js libraries files and used it then it worked. I think the problem is from the npm installation, so you can check how to install desintegrate https://github.com/ZachSaucier/Disintegrate and try again.

[techibytes](https://techibytes.com)